# Syncing files on ubuntu one

Tags: software-installation

My laptop had a problem, so I reinstalled Kubuntu 12.04LTS. In that re-installation I lost the previously installed U1. So now I've reinstalled U1 too. But my question is, will it download previously uploaded folders? And if the answer is yes, then how to stop U1 from downloading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open Ubuntu One, enter your email and password, you will be offered to choose which previously uploaded folder(s) and/or files to synchronize with the "current" computer. If you do not choose any folders from the list, nothing will be downloaded, but the files will still be on the Ubuntu One server.

The only folder that is -always- synchronized is the Ubuntu One folder itself (`~/Ubuntu One`).